# I don't know why '\n' new line is not working

Tags: apex, visualforce

My controller code is as follows -

```
       for(String resStr : responseArray){
            if(resStr.indexOf('r_error_str') != -1){
                responseString += resStr.substring(resStr.indexOf('=') + 1); 
                responseString += '\n';
            }
        }
```

but when i display this 'responseString ' String using 'apex:outputLabel or apex:outputText or as Exception message '\n' is not converting in new line. Whole String is coming in one line.

Can anyone explain why is this happining

Answer (score 10, accepted):

just use `<br/>` in controller and `escape="false"` in visualforce text.

Comment: This does work of course, but if you're looking to publish on the AppExchange the use of `escape="false"` will be heavily frowned upon (from experience).

Comment: It is not working if i set message in user define exception object as message and rending that at visual force page. It is showing <br/> at visual force error message.

Comment: It works as expected.

Answer (score 8):

The simple answer is using '\n' will not work in HTML elements as it is just basically white space, google your problem and you'll get lots of results.

Could you possibly 'repeat' in your VF on the responseArray?

Answer (score 7):

```
  currentAddress = currentStreet;
        currentAddress += '\r\n';
        currentAddress += currentCity + + ' ' + currentState  + ' ' + currentZIP ;
        currentAddress += '\r\n';
        currentAddress += currentCountry;
```

using the '\r\n' works with outputtext .Please try same

Comment: Hey this worked for LWC's JS as well!

Answer (score 3):

I was trying the line breaks (\r\n) in a trigger, and couldn't get them to work, so I tried adding a non-breaking space character, and that worked like a charm.

```
   for(String resStr : responseArray){
        if(resStr.indexOf('r_error_str') != -1){
            responseString += resStr.substring(resStr.indexOf('=') + 1); 
            responseString += '&nbsp;';
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In Apex class to break the line you need to use below code.[image]

Comment: This is the same as an existing answer from 10 years ago, but with less information.