# Add a new line in the value attribute on Date display: apex outputtext

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have the below value printing the date as below:

```
Monday, January 1,
1800
```

But would like the date to split in the new line (only the Day) like below:

```
Monday
January 1, 1800
```

Salesforce Code:

```
<apex:outputText value="{0,date,EEEE',' MMMMM d',' yyyy}">
    <apex:param value="{c.CreatedDate}" />
</apex:outputText>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
<apex:outputText value="{0,date,EEEE'<br/>'MMMMM d',' yyyy}" escape="false">
```

[image]

Upvote the answer from the question below :) :

[I don't know why '\n' new line is not working](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/5676/i-dont-know-why-n-new-line-is-not-working)