# Line break (\n) in return statement of a method

Tags: apex, webservices, apexrest, line-break

I am trying to use Line breaks (\n) in return statement. But it doesn't work. \n gets printed in the return statement. I am not using any VF Page. I am trying this in my webservice class.

Below is the method structure.

```
global static string createNewCase()
{
    //...
    return 'FIELDS :' + '' + response.fields + '/\n' +
        'MESSAGE :' + '' + response.message +
        'STATUS CODE :' + '' + response.statuscode;
}
```

I tried by adding '/\n' this also did not work. Please help in how to do this. I tried to search for this. But all I get is the example of VF page and controller where escape=False is specified in controller.

I have tried the code mentioned in the [I don't know why '\n' new line is not working](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/5676/i-dont-know-why-n-new-line-is-not-working) link for reference and made changes. Still it is not working.

Comment: Hi Basti, Thanks for the reply. But this is not the same question that you mentioned. I am not using any VF page. I am trying to return string from a method.

Comment: FYI you can remove your concatenations of the empty string (`''`) as they add nothing.

Comment: @AdrianLarson The concatenations were used for adding whitespace. I will remove them. Yes you are right they add nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You may use like following:

```
String str = 'Welcome home'; 
str += '\n';
str += 'salesforce stackExchange';
return str;

output: 
Welcome home 
salesforce stackExchange
```

Comment: Hi @Prince. I already tried what you have given. But that is not working.